# js Добавить объекты в массив используя currentTarget

Tags: javascript, jquery

Идея в том что бы при вводе каких то данных в инпут, собранные с текущего поля попадали в массив.

Вообщем, что я только не перебирал. у меня или **массив сам себя перезаписывает** в index:0 или object object, на ютубе гайды не помогают, везде примитивная лажа типо отсортируйте массив профильтруйте массив, сделайте сплит или сплайт...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 $(formID).find('input[required]').on('keyup', (event) => this.reviewFormValidatKeyup(event) + this.reviewFormValidatEmail());

  reviewFormValidatKeyup(event) {
   let target = $(event.currentTarget);
    let arr = [];
    let obj = [{ 'id': target.attr('id'), 'name': target.attr('name'), 'data-input': target.attr('data-input') }];

    arr = obj.map((index, elem) => {
        return arr += index;
    });
   }
```

Получаю в результат:

```
arr ["[object Object]"]0: "[object Object]"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Или единожды:

```
0:{id: "review-form-email", name: "email", data-input: "false"}
 length:1
 __proto__:Array(0)
```

я знаю про push pop shift unshift, перечитайте еще раз вопрос, а потом трясите золотой медалью по js

я не понимаю как добавить в массив новый объект, пуш перезаписывает index 0

```
arr.push(obj)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: arr.push(obj[0])

Comment: Чот какая-то каша ... может вам все же начать с разбора "примитивной лажи"? `return` - это вообще какая-то магия вне Хогвартса. Не видно где вообще попытка работать с инпутами, а не перебор массива что бы засунуть в другой массив ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev обновил

Comment: _я знаю про push pop shift unshift_, _пуш перезаписывает index 0_ - два, взаимоисключающих выражения.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос [mcve]. Иначе непонятно, что именно ты пытаешься сделать. По твоему коду непонято какой результат ты хочешь получить. Не говоря про то, что ты неверно используешь метод [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: По поводу заголовка: `currentTarget` - никаким боком не относится к массиву, следовательно с его помощью нельзя добавить элемент в массив.

Comment: @Grundy _ты неверно используешь метод_ - серьезно? Если бы я знал как правильно, я бы не создавал тему на форуме логично? | 
_с его помощью нельзя добавить элемент в массив_ - все можно, | 
Я даже фото приложил. опытный middle давно бы понял мою проблему, видимо тут такие же новички как и я =\

Comment: @AnnaJ.Rittle, посмотри ответы по второму вопросу дубликату. Так поясняется что именно у тебя не так.

Comment: @Grundy Подскажите, зачем мне count в переменную если я пытаюсь объект в массив засунуть?

Comment: @AnnaJ.Rittle, затем, что если ты сменишь название count на arr, выйдет именно твой случай. Только в том вопрос пытались менять число, а у тебя массив, проблема при этом одна и та же. В обработчике и там и тут _заново_ создается переменная, которая в нем и меняется.

Comment: @Grundy не помогло, есть варианты?

Comment: @AnnaJ.Rittle, это единственно верный вариант. Если у тебя не работает, очевидно, ты делаешь что-то не так. Что конкретно - нельзя сказать, пока не будет предоставлен [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy вы меня троллите, так как сверху написано единственное событие по кейапу, все там больше ничего нет. о каком коде речь?

Comment: @AnnaJ.Rittle, например, о том, который можно запустить и увидеть ошибку. Об этом можно было прочитать по ссылке в комментариях выше. А так же, код, в котором _не помогло_. Так как неизвестно что и как было изменено в коде - нельзя сказать что именно было неправильно применено и почему не помогло.

Comment: @Grundy хорошо я перенесу в песочницу